# How to create an alias (shortened version) for a long list of CL commands?

Tags: linux, bash

So I've got a long list of commands that I need to run over and over (using Linux terminal)...
Example:

```
./path/foo --input_file <something interesting>
           --output_file <should equal input + random suffix> 
           --other_flags <need freedom here>
./path/bar --input_file <should be same input file>
           --input_file2 <should be same as output file>
           --output_file <should be original input name with some prefix>
```

So how do you compose a string like this in bash maybe and run it?

Comment: Why CL in the title? It made me think of Common Lisp ....

Comment: Use a function in your ~/.bashrc. See `help function`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I mean command line

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks - will check this out

Answer (score 1):

You could add some executable shell script in a directory mentioned by your [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29).

You could also define some [shell functions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-shell-functions.htm) for your interactive shells, typically in your `~/.bashrc`

Comment: I just need to run the same commands over and over and some of the inputs are redundant and could be decided by other inputs. Right now I've a tiny Python script that outputs the command line string. I just don't like using Python for something so simple.

Comment: What is wrong with a tiny Python script, if you are familiar with Python?